# How send push notification from windows app

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I want to send a push notification for Windows phone 8.1, from a desktop windows app.

I found this example:

```
private static async void SendNotificationAsync()
    {
        // Define the notification hub.
        NotificationHubClient hub =
            NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
                "Endpoint=sb://...notificationhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=9w3Mo....NNcDRI=", "MinskTransNotificationBeta");

        // Create an array of breaking news categories.
        var categories = new string[] { "World", "Politics", "Business", 
    "Technology", "Science", "Sports"};

        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            try
            {
                // Define a Windows Store toast.
                //var wnsToast = "<toast><visual><binding template=\"ToastText01\">"
                //  + "<text id=\"1\">Breaking " + category + " News!"
                //  + "</text></binding></visual></toast>";
                //await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(wnsToast, category);

                // Define a Windows Phone toast.
                var mpnsToast =
                    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                    "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                        "<wp:Toast>" +
                            "<wp:Text1>Breaking " + category + " News!</wp:Text1>" +
                        "</wp:Toast> " +
                    "</wp:Notification>";
                await hub.SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync(mpnsToast, category);


            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                // An exception is raised when the notification hub hasn't been 
                // registered for the iOS, Windows Store, or Windows Phone platform. 
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get exception NotFound

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingEntityNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found. No service is hosted at the specified
>   address..TrackingId:7443c7a8-....c03f7da9_G4,TimeStamp:6/1/2015
>   9:22:48 PM

Answer (score 0):

Check service at this endpoint.

Most likely an error in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Check

- Enable Unauthenticated push notifications from Azure Portal.
- Check your Connection String and be sure that you are using FullSharedAccesKey.(Your SAS name must match within the string in your Connection String)
- You have an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are spelling the NH name correctly or if you have "MinskTransNotificationBeta" actually in the portal.

So mainly this kind of error is Setup/configuration error and it's recommended to review your configuration and change if necessary.

you can check this [link](https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Feur04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com%2F%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flearn.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Fazure%252Fservice-bus-messaging%252Fservice-bus-messaging-exceptions%26data%3D02%257C01%257C%257C9bc65a4f3f274980593208d6538a0ce2%257C84df9e7fe9f640afb435aaaaaaaaaaaa%257C1%257C0%257C636788249711318331%26sdata%3DKqKZ1nzclqPt%252Fn3%252FH4RmaBnMioCsBO1rl1GX0C7EP3M%253D%26reserved%3D0&data=02%7C01%7Ca-amalhu%40microsoft.com%7Cc07b9ff2c26043d7571d08d6544e5c7a%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636789092887644068&sdata=6vBksVsIfJAudobAYknH47Z3b3RUFyAunMNNUD88mLE%3D&reserved=0) to know further about this error.